# wfastcgi-enable failed to create process

Tags: python, django, pip, command-prompt, wfastcgi

When I install python first time, wfastcgi-enable didn't have any problem.
But when I uninstall and reinstall, it happened like this!

Command Prompt

```
C:\Windows\system32>pip install wfastcgi
Collecting wfastcgi
  Using cached wfastcgi-3.0.0.tar.gz (14 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for wfastcgi, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: wfastcgi
    Running setup.py install for wfastcgi ... done
Successfully installed wfastcgi-3.0.0

C:\Windows\system32>wfastcgi-enable
failed to create process.
```

My python install place.
C:\Users\Civil\Python38

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same issue, and I failed catching the exact reason.

But I found a workaround.

```
cd C:\Users\Civil\Python38\Scripts

python wfastcgi-enable-script.py
```

In this manner, I could enable wfastcgi.